# How do I include both a left and right sidemenu in ionic v4?

Tags: ionic4, right-to-left, left-to-right

I am trying to use a single menu for both LTR and RTL but the issue I am facing when its RTL then the menu is opening from the left side which should be from the right side

Comment: can you add some code what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can use a single menu for both RTL and LTR swiping behavior. You could instead, use a service that would populate the menu information with a `*ngIf=let link of links"`, and then just have a menu on either side of the app that subscribes to the links provided in the service.

The attribute `side="end"` or `side="start"` controls which side of the app the menu will appear on, so if you want to swipe from the right side of the screen you'd use `slide="end"` on your `ion-menu`.

```
<ion-menu side="end" contentId="mainContent" menuId="slidingMenu" id="slidingMenu">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>{{(menu?.details | async)?.title}}</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-mute">
        <ion-label>Mute</ion-label>
        <ion-toggle></ion-toggle>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let link of (menu?.details | async)?.links" detail
                (click)="navToPage(link)">{{link?.title}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```